# Highlight the first item in view pager when the activity loads while using custom view with tab layout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, android-tablayout

I am working on tabs like the youtube app and would like to highlight the first page on load of the activity so i used the following code

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);//which does not highlight first tab onstarting the tab activity
```

And i used  drawable as background for the icons in tablayout . I set the background of drawable on create of fragment by getting each child of tablayout . I set the text color in

```
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTextAppearance</item>

</style>
<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

One of the selector files

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorite_selected" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorite_selected" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/favorite_selected" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/favorites" />
    </selector>
```

There are two other drawables and i am using custom layout for tabs 
How can i show the first item highlighted when the app loads in view pager

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not selected?  Is this strictly about the background color of the selected tab?

Comment: what is your first item?

Comment: When the tab activity gets loaded , i want the first item to be highlighted like in the youtube app . Right now first item is not selected by default but when user swipes the item gets selected .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky.

[image]

You should set background in this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I.e. change `android:background` to `app:tabBackground`

Now once you press on the tab - it get's proper background `drawable`.

To apply selector to icons in TabLayout:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_i_selector);
}
```

#### UPD:

After going back and forth, together with *@Preethi* we've solved it:

```
 tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
```

**Important note.** *@Preethi* is using `setCustomView()` method to set the `View`s for the `Tab`s.

Another possible workaround would be to avoid custom views and set TextColor&Icons this way:

```
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getColor(R.color.normal_color), getColor(R.color.selected_color));
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_selector);
    }
```

Comment: It surely helps . But let us say each tab(three tabs)  has drawable and text .I have added the text selector and image drawable selector files in the question

Comment: @Preethi Ok, and what's the question? Icons, can be also wrapped into selector and set: (in cycle) `tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon_i_selector);` ; TextAppearance can be set in the layout via `app:tabTextAppearance=..`

Comment: I did the same thing but the first item never appears selected when tab activity is displayed

Comment: @Preethi i.e. you need to click one more time on it to select the first tab, right?

Comment: Oops meant the first item never appears selected . Like in youtube app when you open the home icon is highlighted and is white , same way i need favorites to be selected and icon to be changed when the user first opens the activity

Comment: @Preethi if you just `viewPager.setAdapter(...);` and then `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` - the first item is gonna be selected by default in TabLayout (and ViewPager shows the first page). Can you post your Activity's code , where you setting them up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99247/discussion-between-konstantin-loginov-and-preethi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99326/discussion-between-preethi-and-konstantin-loginov).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to select the first item inside the viewpager, or the first tab?
For the latter, try

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

instead of

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: Added this code on OnCreate and still the first items is not selected .